# Cannot pass array to parameter in AWS StepFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions, amazon-emr

I'm working on AWS StepFunction with EMR.
My input looks like this.

```json
{
  "dt":"20210101"
}
```

Because I wanted to run spark-submit in EMR, I added a step with HadoopJarStep.
My step looks like this.

```json
    "Run first step": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
        "Step": {
          "Name": "My first EMR step",
          "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
          "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args.$": "States.Array('spark-submit','--deploy-mode','client', 's3://script_path.py','s3://some_path', '$.dt')"
          }
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.firstStep",
      "Next": "Terminate Cluster"
```

My problem point is here `"Args.$": "States.Array('spark-submit','--deploy-mode','client', 's3://script_path.py','s3://some_path', '$.dt')"`.

I have to pass parameters as an array for the step but the "$.dt" doesn't work properly.

I tried various way like below

```
"Args.$": "States.Array('spark-submit','--deploy-mode','client', 's3://script_path.py','States.Format(\\'s3://some_path\\', $.dt)')"
"Args.$": "States.Array('spark-submit','--deploy-mode','client', 's3://script_path.py','States.Format(s3://some_path, $.dt)')"
"Args.$": "['spark-submit','--deploy-mode','client', 's3://script_path.py','s3://some_path/$.dt']"
```

but it never successes.

How can I pass parameters as an array with interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the quotes around $.dt, that resolved this for me:

```
"Args.$": "States.Array('spark-submit','--deploy-mode','client', 's3://script_path.py','s3://some_path', $.dt)"
```